# Regex matching only prefix or only suffix (XOR)

Tags: java, regex

I have a pattern, which I'll refer to as `Z` (actual pattern is a bit long and not important to the question). Simply put, I want to be able to match either `\*\sZ`, or `Z\:`, but not both nor neither.

I attempted using lookaheads (similar to below), however because of the pattern between the prefix and suffix they wouldn't work.

```
(\*\s(?!\:))Z((?<!\*)\:)
```

Is there a way of accomplishing this without having to duplicate the pattern (e.g. `(\*\sZ|Z\:)`)?

A quick note about my pattern is there is no `\*` in the `Z` pattern, only in the prefix. Conversely there's also no `\:` in the Z pattern, it's only in the suffix if *immediately proceeding* Z, but not after any other characters (there's a `.*` capture after the suffix)

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: @ndn java, though I've been using an online `pcre` tester for simplicity.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that in java with regex only. Extract `Z` in separate string and use it to create the overall pattern so you don't have to duplicate it.

Comment: Try `((?:^|\b)pre)\S+|\S+?suf(?:\b|$)` , where pre = prefix and suf = suffix. It will capture all words with given prefix or suffix.

Comment: How about this https://regex101.com/r/rE3lP8/1 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way of accomplishing this without having to duplicate the
>   pattern?

The answer is "NO". Unlike `and` and `or` which are fundamental properties of regular expression. In regular expression, you can easily construct `and` expression by using `concatenation` and construct `or` expression by using `|` respectively.

But anyway, if you still want get your job done I suggest you to do this.

First, you already had two patterns here

```
\*\sZ
```

and

```
Z\:
```

So, as you said, these two patterns could not be occurred at the same time.

So from properties of `xor`:

> A xor B = (A & ~B)|(~A & B).

Finally, we can get

```
\*\sZ(?!\:)|(?<!\*\s)Z\:
```

See a [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rE3lP8/1)

Comment: Even though OP said one or the other, he just meant simple `|`. He was just wondering how not to duplicate `Z`.

Comment: He said "Is there a way of accomplishing this without having to duplicate the pattern?". The answer is "no" because `XOR` is not a fundamental building block of regex.

Comment: I answered "NO" already and suggested him the way to done what he said "I want to be able to match either `\*\sZ`, or `Z\:`, but not both nor neither." which I gave one regex for him on my answer.

Comment: Accepted for now, I was fairly certain this was the case but was hoping for something magic I didn't know of in regex. I just held the pattern in a variable and concat'd that way.